# Fetching the value from tables based on some filter condition and pass it to the other table

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I want to get the value from the table based on the condition. For example I have a table called `studentinfo` with two fields `studentsid` and `status`. Now I have to fetch the `status` value through the query based on the `studentsid`, i.e. if the student id is 1. I need the status value of the student which has the `studentsid` as 1.

```
student_status = studentinfo.query.filter(studentinfo.student_id==1).all()
```

After I gave this query I am getting

```
[studentinfo(1,'Present')]
```

What I need here is I have to store the `'Present'` and use it further.

Answer (score 0):

If you only expect a single match, you can run the query with this:

```
student_status = studentinfo.query.filter( studentinfo.student_id==1 ).first()
```

where I switched the `.all()` method with `.first()`. This would allow you to directly extract the information like this:

```
status = student_status.status
... do something with variable status on another table
```

However, if there can potentially be multiple selections, you can keep your query line and extract them with something along the lines of this:

```
student_status = studentinfo.query.filter( studentinfo.student_id==1 ).all()
for student in student_status:
    status = student[ 'status' ]
    ... do something with variable status on different table
```

In this way, you can loop through every student with `student_id==1` and run your next query on a different table.

Comment: Thanks Jason,When I try with first , I am getting an error mention that student_status['status'] is not subscriptable.So I followed your second option and it worked well

Comment: You're right. I made a mistake in my first example. I updated it if you were still interested in the first solution.